# hive transactional table compaction fails

Tags: hive, acid

Table created with this :

```
create table syslog_staged (id string, facility string, sender string, severity string, tstamp string, service string, msg string) partitioned by (hostname string,  year string, month string, day string) clustered by (id) into 20 buckets stored as orc tblproperties("transactional"="true");
```

the table is populated with Apache nifi's PutHiveStreaming...

```
alter table syslog_staged partition (hostname="cloudserver19", year="2016", month="10", day="24") compact 'major';
```

Now it turns out compaction fails for some reason.....(from job history)

```
No of maps and reduces are 0 job_1476884195505_0031
Job commit failed: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File hdfs://hadoop1.openstacksetup.com:8020/apps/hive/warehouse/log.db/syslog_staged/hostname=cloudserver19/year=2016/month=10/day=24/_tmp_27c40005-658e-48c1-90f7-2acaa124e2fa does not exist.
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.listStatusInternal(DistributedFileSystem.java:904)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.access$600(DistributedFileSystem.java:113)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$21.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:966)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$21.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:962)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.listStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:962)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.txn.compactor.CompactorMR$CompactorOutputCommitter.commitJob(CompactorMR.java:776)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCommitter.commitJob(OutputCommitter.java:291)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.commit.CommitterEventHandler$EventProcessor.handleJobCommit(CommitterEventHandler.java:285)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.commit.CommitterEventHandler$EventProcessor.run(CommitterEventHandler.java:237)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
```

from hive metastore log :

```
2016-10-24 16:33:35,503 WARN  [Thread-14]: compactor.Initiator (Initiator.java:run(132)) - Will not initiate compaction for log.syslog_staged.hostname=cloudserver19/year=2016/month=10/day=24 since last hive.compactor.initiator.failed.compacts.threshold attempts to compact it failed.
```

Answer (score 0):

Please set below properties for optimizing compaction for transactional table-

`set hive.compactor.worker.threads=1;
set hive.compactor.initiator.on=true;`

I assume you have set below transactional Hive properties

`set hive.txn.manager=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lockmgr.DbTxnManager;
set hive.support.concurrency=true;
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
set hive.enforce.bucketing=true;`